# Does a ring of spell storing have a use if it is found with 0 spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

A ring of spell storing has 1d6-1 spells. If I find the ring with 0 spells, as I actually did, does the ring still have a use?

Comment: Since you aren't sure what to do with that Ring, perhaps you should send it to my Warlock -- I'd love to be able to store up spells like *hunger of Hadar* and *armor of Agathys* on slow days, so I can use them when I wish I had more slots...

Comment: Haha, maybe I should.

Comment: "A bowl us most useful when it is empty" -Laozi

Comment: @ZeissIkon Only drawback of a Warlock with a Ring of Spell Storing is that once you get to where all your spells are cast at 3rd level you can only put 1 spell into it... nice thing is you can have your cleric put spells in it to keep you healed... especially if you are a bladelock.

Comment: Ah, I don't have access to a DMG, and the link in the first answer below is blocked from my work computer, so wasn't aware it only takes spells up to 3rd or that it limits by level x slots.  Takes one spell up to 5th, though, right?  *Armor of Agathys* is best when upcast...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Right, limit of 5 spell levels and as a warlock always upcasts eventually they can only ever put one spell at a time in... still that gives you like an extra slot every other short rest which isn't anything to sneeze at obviously which sort of balances out since wizards could put more spells in but not recharge except after every long rest.

Comment: @Slagmoth I certainly wouldn't throw one away if I acquired it...  ;)  As you say, like getting an extra slot every other rest.  That is *nontrivial* when you're only getting two or three.  And having room for the cleric to load in a couple *cure wounds* or similar is gravy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ring of Spell Storing states:

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell Attack bonus, and Spellcasting Ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell. The spell cast from the ring is no longer stored in it, freeing up space a spell by way of expending any leftover spell slots, of course.
>   This ring stores Spells cast into it, holding them until the attuned wearer uses them.

You need to specify which spell slots are being taken from you and placed into the Ring in order for those spell slots to be utilized when using the ring as an action.

It's the end of the day and you found that you used too many cantrips (no such thing if you're still alive) and have a few spell slots kicking around.  Why waste them? Save them and carry them forward via The Ring of Storing.

Just clarifying that filling the ring would in fact still cost the caster a spell slot. The ring effectively STEALS one of your spell slots so that you can use it at another given time.

This is the opposite of an Artificier at LvL 11, for instance, who can store spells into a weapon or casting focus after a Long Rest.  Not affecting your daily spell slots.

Comment: Also note that the artificer doesn't store spells with an action. He stores his spell with a long rest.

Comment: I just wanted to basically state that a Level 9 Druid can't use their only Level 5 Spell slot and then later the same day store a level 5 spell into the ring.  You are effectively casting the spell, and then holding its effects until a later moment in time.

Answer (score 23):

## Yes, you can cast spells into it

Either you or someone you know or can hire who has spellcasting can put spells into the [ring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) (DMG, 192):

> Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast.